# Need to destroy a dijit DropDownMenu, getting error

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a programmatic dijit/DropDownMenu, which works fine on initial load. I need to reload the menu each time the customer enters a new year. If I understand the dijit documentation correctly, the top IF statement here should do the job of destroying the old menu and its descendants, all sitting in a DIV with `id="clientDropdowns"`. Instead, I am getting:

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method '_subnodeCssMouseEvent'

when I place the mouse cursor on the supposedly new menu. I cannot open it as a result of that error. Any ideas what could be the problem here or possible workarounds? Much appreciated.

```
if (dijit.byId('clientDropdowns')) {
  dijit.byId('clientDropdowns').destroyRecursive(true);
} 

mymenu = new dijit.DropDownMenu({}, "clientDropdowns");
submenu = new dijit.DropDownMenu({});
popumenuitem = new dijit.PopupMenuItem({ label: "Select  Program", popup: submenu });

...

mymenu.addChild(popumenuitem);  
mymenu.startup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found workaround - supplementation by dojo.empty() does the trick

```
if (dijit.byId('clientDropdown')) { 
dijit.byId('clientDropdown').destroyRecursive(true); 
dojo.empty('clientDropdown'); 
}
```